# How to validate that the entry of a number is not with "0" in C #

Tags: c#, parsing, xamarin, mvvm, string-formatting

I have a control of type `<Entry>` in which I don't want the user to enter values ​​that start with "0", for example...

> 0
>
> 01
>
> 00
>
> 00010

But if I want to enter values ​​that contain "0" in the form of natural numbers, for example ...

> 10
>
> 2010
>
> 200000

`MyView.XAML`:

```
<Entry
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      Placeholder="Cantidad"
      Keyboard="Numeric"
      MaxLength="9"
      Text="{Binding CantidadContenedor}"></Entry>
```

`MyViewModel.CS`:

```
   string cantidadContenedor;

   public string CantidadContenedor
        {
            get
            {
                return  cantidadContenedor;
            }
            set
            {
                if (cantidadContenedor != value)
                {
                    cantidadContenedor = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CantidadContenedor)));
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I add this validation once I capture the value of the `Entry`?

Can I occupy the `TryParse` Property being a `Container Quantity` of type `string`?

Any help for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a validation rule.

In your XAML

```
<Entry
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  Placeholder="Cantidad"
  Keyboard="Numeric"
  MaxLength="9">
  <Entry.Text>
     <Binding Path=CantidadContenedor>
         <Binding.ValidationRules>
             <validationRules:StartWithRule Prefix="0"/>
     </Binding>
  </Entry.Text>
</Entry>
```

Now you crate the validation you see fit. In your case

```
public class StartWithRule : ValidationRule
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        // Pass the value to string
        var numberToCheck = (string) value;

        if (numberToCheck == null) return ValidationResult.ValidResult;

        // Check if it starts with prefix
        return numberToCheck.StartsWith(Prefix)
            ? new ValidationResult(false, $"Starts with {Prefix}")
            : ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

And you should be good to go.

[image: Valid Number] [image: Invalid Number]

Answer (score 4):

This one working perfect !!

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyEntry.TextChanged+= MyEntry_TextChanged;
    }

    void MyEntry_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyEntry.Text))
        {
            if (MyEntry.Text.StartsWith("0"))
                MyEntry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not a very mvvm solution imo

Answer (score 1):

You could just cast whatever value you're receiving as a `string`.

Then just read the first digit as a substring like so:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string x = "0TEST";
        if(x.StartsWith("0")){
            Console.WriteLine("Starts with 0");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Doesn't start with 0");
        }
    }
}
```

Then write in the logic to allow/deny it.

Comment: could shorten the test with x.StartsWith("0")